# Preenchendo textbox de um formulario com informações de um datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms

Tenho um datagrideview em um formulário, e preciso que quando clique na célula de datagridview ele preencha dois campos em outro form.

Como mostro na imagem abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

segue também meu código

```
public partial class frmFaturaAnual : Form
{

    SqlConnection conexao = null;
    SqlCommand comando = null;

    public frmFaturaAnual()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ListaGrid()
    {
        string strSQL = @"SELECT 
                          RTRIM(B1_COD) + ' - ' + B1_DESC AS PRODUTO, 
                          [Janeiro], [Fevereiro], [Março], [Abril], [Maio], [Junho], [Julho], 
                          [Agosto], [Setembro], [Outubro], [Novembro], [Dezembro] 
      FROM ( SELECT SB.B1_COD, SB.B1_DESC, m.nm_mes, SD.D2_QUANT FROM  SD2010 AS SD left outer join mes m on m.cd_mes = month(SD.D2_EMISSAO) 
      INNER JOIN SB1010 AS SB WITH (NOLOCK) ON SB.B1_COD = SD.D2_COD 
      WHERE SD.D_E_L_E_T_ <> '*' 
      AND SD.D2_CF IN ('5102', '5117', '5119', '5123', '5124', '5403', '5405', '6102', '6108', '6110', '6117', '6119', '6123', '6124', '6403', '6405', '7102') 
      AND YEAR(SD.D2_EMISSAO) = '" + txtAno.Text +"' ) AS F PIVOT (SUM(D2_QUANT) FOR nm_mes IN  ([Janeiro], [Fevereiro], [Março], [Abril], [Maio], [Junho], [Julho], [Agosto], [Setembro], [Outubro], [Novembro], [Dezembro])) AS P";

        conexao = new SqlConnection(conm);
        comando = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conexao);

        try
        {
            SqlDataAdapter dados = new SqlDataAdapter(comando);
            DataTable dtLista = new DataTable();
            dados.Fill(dtLista);

            dgAnual.DataSource = dtLista;
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Não existem dados a serem encontrados");
        }
    }

    private void btnPesquisar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ListaGrid();
    }

    private void btnFechar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Close();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frmImpFatAnual imp = new frmImpFatAnual(txtAno.Text);
        imp.Show();
    }

    private void dgAnual_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    { 

        frmQtdaCliente custo = new frmQtdaCliente(txtAno.Text);
        custo.Show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considerando que, você vá utilizar o evento doubleclick no datagridview, e que sempre será aberto um novo form, quando o evento ocorrer:

no seu frmQtdaCliente, crie duas propriedades

```
public string Mes {get;set;}
public string Produto {get;set;}
```

no evento load do form, preencha os textbox.

para chamar o form, no evento dgAnual_CellDoubleClick:

```
frmQtdaCliente custo = new frmQtdaCliente(txtAno.Text);
custo.Mes= dgAnual.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cell["nome da sua coluna mes"].Value.ToString();
custo.Produto = dgAnual.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cell["nome da sua coluna produto"].Value.ToString();
```

custo.Show();

Comment: Rovann ate deu certo seu procedimento, mas no txtMes eu preciso do nome do Mes sendo preenchido no txtbox, do jeito que esta seu código esta trazendo o txtMes o conteúdo da célula, não e isso que quero, e sim o nome da coluna que estou selecionando a celula.

Comment: Na hora de preencher a variável mês, utilize dgAnual.Colums[e.ColumnIndex].Name

Comment: Desculpe se tiver algum erro na sintaxe, estou no celular, se ajudou, marca como resposta por favor

Comment: Obrigado deu certinho aqui vlw

Comment: Agora estou com outro erro em algumas colunas quando cliko. 
 Ocorreu uma exceção sem tratamento do tipo "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException" em System.Data.dll

Informações adicionais: Divide by zero error encountered.

Comment: aí temos que ver onde exatamente acontece o outro erro, se é nesse primeiro form, ou no outro, Divide by zero está acontecendo em algum cálculo de um comando sql. No evento double click, convém colocar o trecho "if(e.RowIndex < 0 || e.ColumnIndex < 0)  return;"  para não entrar no código se for clicado em um header. Por favor, marque como resposta

Comment: Bom dia Rovann. Engraçado que só acontece na coluna do Mes de Janeiro do datagriview, as outras colunas funcionam normalmente.

Comment: possívelmente pelo valor 0 (zerado) que tenta realizar a divisão, mostre a sintaxe sql para tentar te ajudar, se possível o código do outro form

Comment: amigo, você marcou a resposta do outro membro como resposta da sua questão !? Não que a dele esteja errada, também funciona, mas marque a minha também

Comment: Me desculpe acho que agora marquei certo.

Answer (score 1):

Há diversas maneiras de se fazer isso. Eu quase sempre opto pela ideia de enviar os dados via construtor para o novo *form*, isso facilita colocar valores nos controles logo depois que eles forem criados e também impede que estes controles sejam acessados fora do *form*.

Minha dica se baseia, basicamente, em três coisas a fazer

1. Adicionar um evento de *click* (ou *double click*) no `DataGridView` (não nas células - porque o evento é disparado em qualquer lugar da linha que for clicado, se você não quer isto use o evento `CellDoubleClick` mesmo);
2. Capturar as informações necessárias;
3. Passar estas informações como parâmetro no construtor do novo *form*.

Exemplo:

```
private void dgAnual_DoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{ 
    if(e.RowIndex < 0 || e.ColumnIndex < 0)
        return;

    var row = dgAnual.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    var nomeProduto = row["NomeDaColunaProduto"].Value;
    var mes = row["NomeDaColunaMes"].Value;

    FormNovo form = new FormNovo(nomeProduto, mes);
    form.Show();
}
```